# 'You had Konklin [name] killed'. What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, causative-have

I've heard this in a movie called [The Bourne Supremacy](https://g.co/kgs/bLovG2). I am not really good with English so can anybody help me out?

What does '**You had Konklin killed**' mean?
*By the way, Konklin is just a character's name*

Comment: You found someone who killed  Konklin for you.

Comment: It means that the person being addressed is being accused of arranging for Konklin's murder.

Comment: It's the same structure as "I had the car washed." To have something done is to get some agent to do the thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The syntax of "have something done"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282253/the-syntax-of-have-something-done)

Comment: This is using meaning 2.5 from [this Lexico entry](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/have): "[with past participle] Cause (something) to be done for one by someone else. *‘it is advisable to have your carpet laid by a professional’*" That is, *have* plus an object plus a past participle (in this case *killed*) equals "Cause [the object] to be [participled]."

Comment: I'm leaving this question open because if you don't recognize or understand passive causative grammar, you might not know what to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This structure is called *passive causative*.

The form is: *["have/get" + object + past participle]*

The meaning is to *cause or arrange for someone else to do something*, and not do it yourself.

Some examples:

> 1. I had the house painted.
> 2. I got my hair done.
> 3. I had your office cleaned.

In these examples, I arranged for painters to paint my house, I asked my barber to cut my hair, and I told the cleaning staff to clean your office.

In your example, it means, "You arranged for someone to kill Konklin", which probably means you hired an assassin to kill Konklin, or put out a contract on Konklin's life.